# How to disable Gecko driver logs when running testNG xml file from eclipse

Tags: selenium

1480071518229   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:1749
Nov 25, 2016 4:28:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1480071518762   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.L7LGwBLkdzD6
1480071518774   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
1480071518783   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:59731
1480071518961   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1480071519005   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1480071519007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1480071519010   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
1480071519011   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/PluginProvider.jsm
1480071519012   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: XPIProvider
1480071519012   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1480071519013   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
1480071519014   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping loop@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1480071519014   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1480071519015   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1480071519016   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, which redirects these browser logs to a separate file rather than the console -

```
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true");
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"C:\\temp\\logs.txt");
```

For more information, you check refer this article - [Disable Firefox logs](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/disable-firefox-logs-selenium/)